# Magento 2, admin dashboard shows some error while selecting all products and updating them all together

Tags: magento2, backend

> ***Magento 2 admin dashboard > Catalog > Products > then select all products and click on update attributes,***
>
> gives some error. Please check the screenshot below.

[image: Product page]

**Below is the code of ***inventory.phtml*** file**

```
 <?php

    /** @var Magento\Catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Edit\Tab\Inventory $block */
    ?>
    <script>
        require(['jquery'], function($){
            $('[data-role=toggle-editability-all]').change(function(e) {
                var toggler = $(this);
                var field = toggler.parents('.field');
                var someEditable = $('input[type!="checkbox"], select, textarea', field);
                var someEditableCheckboxes = $('input[type="checkbox"]', field).not(toggler);
                if(someEditableCheckboxes.length){
                    someEditable.prop('disabled', !toggler.prop('checked') || someEditableCheckboxes.prop('checked'));
                    someEditableCheckboxes.prop('disabled', !toggler.prop('checked'));
                } else {
                    someEditable.prop('disabled', !toggler.prop('checked'));
                }
            });
            $('[data-role=toggle-editability]').change(function(e) {
                var useConfigSettings = $(this);
                var field = useConfigSettings.parents('.field');
                var someEditable = $('input[type!="checkbox"], select, textarea', field);
                someEditable.prop('disabled', useConfigSettings.prop('checked'));
            });
        });
    </script>

    <?php
    $defaultMinSaleQty = $block->getDefaultConfigValue('min_sale_qty');
    if (!is_numeric($defaultMinSaleQty)) {
        $defaultMinSaleQty = json_decode($defaultMinSaleQty, true);
        $defaultMinSaleQty = (float) $defaultMinSaleQty[\Magento\Customer\Api\Data\GroupInterface::CUST_GROUP_ALL] ?? 1;
    }
    ?>
    <div class="fieldset-wrapper form-inline advanced-inventory-edit">
        <div class="fieldset-wrapper-title">
            <strong class="title">
                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Advanced Inventory')) ?></span>
            </strong>
        </div>
        <div class="fieldset-wrapper-content">
            <fieldset class="fieldset" id="table_cataloginventory">
            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="inventory_manage_stock">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Manage Stock')) ?></span>
                </label>

                <div class="control">
                    <div class="fields-group-2">
                        <div class="field">
                            <select id="inventory_manage_stock" name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[manage_stock]"
                                    class="select" disabled="disabled">
                                <option value="1"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Yes')) ?></option>
                                <option value="0"
                                    <?php if ($block->getFieldValue('manage_stock') == 0) :?>
                                        selected="selected"
                                    <?php endif; ?>><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No')) ?></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[use_config_manage_stock]" type="checkbox"
                                   id="inventory_use_config_manage_stock" data-role="toggle-editability" value="1"
                                   checked="checked" disabled="disabled"/>
                            <label for="inventory_use_config_manage_stock"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Use Config Settings')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_manage_stock_checkbox" data-role="toggle-editability-all"/>
                            <label for="inventory_manage_stock_checkbox"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field-service" value-scope="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('[GLOBAL]')) ?>"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="field required">
                <label class="label" for="inventory_qty">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty')) ?></span>
                </label>

                <div class="control">
                    <div class="fields-group-2">
                        <div class="field">
                            <input type="text" class="input-text required-entry validate-number" id="inventory_qty"
                                   name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[qty]"
                                   value="<?= $block->getDefaultConfigValue('qty') * 1 ?>" disabled="disabled"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_qty_checkbox" data-role="toggle-editability-all"/>
                            <label for="inventory_qty_checkbox"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field-service" value-scope="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('[GLOBAL]')) ?>"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="field with-addon">
                <label class="label" for="inventory_min_qty">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out-of-Stock Threshold')) ?></span>
                </label>

                <div class="control">
                    <div class="fields-group-2">
                        <div class="field">
                            <input type="text" class="input-text validate-number" id="inventory_min_qty"
                                   name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[min_qty]"
                                   value="<?= $block->getDefaultConfigValue('min_qty') * 1 ?>" disabled="disabled"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_use_config_min_qty"
                                   name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[use_config_min_qty]" value="1"
                                   data-role="toggle-editability" checked="checked" disabled="disabled"/>
                            <label for="inventory_use_config_min_qty" class="label">
                                <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Use Config Settings')) ?></span>
                            </label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_min_qty_checkbox" data-role="toggle-editability-all"/>
                            <label for="inventory_min_qty_checkbox"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field-service" value-scope="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('[GLOBAL]')) ?>"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="inventory_min_sale_qty">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart')) ?></span>
                </label>

                <div class="control">
                    <div class="fields-group-2">
                        <div class="field">
                            <input type="text" class="input-text validate-number" id="inventory_min_sale_qty"
                                   name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[min_sale_qty]"
                                   value="<?= $defaultMinSaleQty * 1 ?>"
                                   disabled="disabled"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_use_config_min_sale_qty"
                                   name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[use_config_min_sale_qty]"
                                   value="1"
                                   data-role="toggle-editability"
                                   checked="checked"
                                   disabled="disabled"/>
                            <label for="inventory_use_config_min_sale_qty"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Use Config Settings')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_min_sale_qty_checkbox" data-role="toggle-editability-all"/>
                            <label for="inventory_min_sale_qty_checkbox"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field-service" value-scope="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('[GLOBAL]')) ?>"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="inventory_max_sale_qty">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Maximum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart')) ?></span>
                </label>

                <div class="control">
                    <div class="fields-group-2">
                        <div class="field">
                            <input type="text" class="input-text validate-number" id="inventory_max_sale_qty"
                                   name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[max_sale_qty]"
                                   value="<?= $block->getDefaultConfigValue('max_sale_qty') * 1 ?>"
                                   disabled="disabled"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   id="inventory_use_config_max_sale_qty"
                                   name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[use_config_max_sale_qty]"
                                   value="1"
                                   data-role="toggle-editability"
                                   checked="checked"
                                   disabled="disabled"/>
                            <label for="inventory_use_config_max_sale_qty"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Use Config Settings')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_max_sale_checkbox" data-role="toggle-editability-all"/>
                            <label for="inventory_max_sale_checkbox"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field-service" value-scope="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('[GLOBAL]')) ?>"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="inventory_is_qty_decimal">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty Uses Decimals')) ?></span>
                </label>

                <div class="control">
                    <div class="fields-group-2">
                        <div class="field">
                            <select id="inventory_is_qty_decimal"
                                    name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[is_qty_decimal]"
                                    class="select"
                                    disabled="disabled">
                                <option value="0"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No')) ?></option>
                                <option value="1"
                                    <?php if ($block->getDefaultConfigValue('is_qty_decimal') == 1) :?>
                                        selected="selected"
                                    <?php endif; ?>><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Yes')) ?></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_is_qty_decimal_checkbox" data-role="toggle-editability-all"/>
                            <label for="inventory_is_qty_decimal_checkbox"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field-service" value-scope="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('[GLOBAL]')) ?>"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="inventory_backorders">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Backorders')) ?></span>
                </label>

                <div class="control">
                    <div class="fields-group-2">
                        <div class="field">
                            <select id="inventory_backorders"
                                    name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[backorders]"
                                    class="select"
                                    disabled="disabled">
                                <?php foreach ($block->getBackordersOption() as $option) :?>
                                    <?php $_selected = ($option['value'] == $block->getDefaultConfigValue('backorders')) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
                                    <option
                                        value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($option['value']) ?>"<?= /* @noEscape */ $_selected ?>><?= $block->escapeHtml($option['label']) ?></option>
                                <?php endforeach; ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_use_config_backorders"
                                   name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[use_config_backorders]"
                                   value="1"
                                   data-role="toggle-editability"
                                   checked="checked"
                                   disabled="disabled"/>
                            <label for="inventory_use_config_backorders"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Use Config Settings')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_backorders_checkbox" data-role="toggle-editability-all"/>
                            <label for="inventory_backorders_checkbox"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
                <div class="field-service" value-scope="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('[GLOBAL]')) ?>"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="inventory_notify_stock_qty">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Notify for Quantity Below')) ?></span>
                </label>

                <div class="control">
                    <div class="fields-group-2">
                        <div class="field">
                            <input type="text" class="input-text validate-number" id="inventory_notify_stock_qty"
                                   name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[notify_stock_qty]"
                                   value="<?= $block->getDefaultConfigValue('notify_stock_qty') * 1 ?>"
                                   disabled="disabled"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   id="inventory_use_config_notify_stock_qty"
                                   name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[use_config_notify_stock_qty]"
                                   value="1"
                                   data-role="toggle-editability"
                                   checked="checked"
                                   disabled="disabled"/>
                            <label for="inventory_use_config_notify_stock_qty"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Use Config Settings')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_notify_stock_qty_checkbox" data-role="toggle-editability-all"/>
                            <label for="inventory_notify_stock_qty_checkbox"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field-service" value-scope="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('[GLOBAL]')) ?>"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="inventory_enable_qty_increments">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Enable Qty Increments')) ?></span>
                </label>

                <div class="control">
                    <div class="fields-group-2">
                        <div class="field">
                            <select id="inventory_enable_qty_increments"
                                    name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[enable_qty_increments]"
                                    class="select"
                                    disabled="disabled">
                                <option value="1"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Yes')) ?></option>
                                <option value="0"
                                    <?php if ($block->getDefaultConfigValue('enable_qty_increments') == 0) :?>
                                        selected="selected"
                                    <?php endif; ?>><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('No')) ?></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_use_config_enable_qty_increments"
                                   name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[use_config_enable_qty_increments]"
                                   value="1"
                                   data-role="toggle-editability"
                                   checked="checked"
                                   disabled="disabled"/>
                            <label for="inventory_use_config_enable_qty_increments"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Use Config Settings')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_enable_qty_increments_checkbox" data-role="toggle-editability-all"/>
                            <label for="inventory_enable_qty_increments_checkbox"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field-service" value-scope="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('[GLOBAL]')) ?>"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="inventory_qty_increments">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Qty Increments')) ?></span>
                </label>

                <div class="control">
                    <div class="fields-group-2">
                        <div class="field">
                            <input type="text" class="input-text validate-number" id="inventory_qty_increments"
                                   name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[qty_increments]"
                                   value="<?= $block->getDefaultConfigValue('qty_increments') * 1 ?>"
                                   disabled="disabled"/>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox"
                                   id="inventory_use_config_qty_increments"
                                   name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[use_config_qty_increments]"
                                   value="1"
                                   data-role="toggle-editability"
                                   checked="checked"
                                   disabled="disabled"/>
                            <label for="inventory_use_config_qty_increments"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Use Config Settings')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_qty_increments_checkbox" data-role="toggle-editability-all"/>
                            <label for="inventory_qty_increments_checkbox"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field-service" value-scope="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('[GLOBAL]')) ?>"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="field">
                <label class="label" for="inventory_stock_availability">
                    <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Stock Availability')) ?></span>
                </label>

                <div class="control">
                    <div class="fields-group-2">
                        <div class="field">
                            <select id="inventory_stock_availability"
                                    name="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getFieldSuffix() ?>[is_in_stock]" class="select"
                                    disabled="disabled">
                                <option value="1"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In Stock')) ?></option>
                                <option value="0"<?php if ($block->getDefaultConfigValue('is_in_stock') == 0) :?> selected<?php endif; ?>><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of Stock')) ?></option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <div class="field choice">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="inventory_stock_availability_checkbox" data-role="toggle-editability-all"/>
                            <label for="inventory_stock_availability_checkbox"
                                   class="label"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Change')) ?></span></label>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="field-service" value-scope="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('[GLOBAL]')) ?>"></div>
            </div>
            </fieldset>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm facing same error in Magento 2.3.3

> main.CRITICAL: Notice: Undefined offset: 32000 in 
>   vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/adminhtml/templates/catalog/product/edit/action/inventory.phtml
>   on line 36

Quick fix for this is to add minimum stock Qty allowed in Shopping Cart:

**Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Inventory -> Minimum Qty Allowed in Shopping Cart**

I set **All Groups to 1**

After this I was able to edit selected products. (options are loading)

Related with some PR on dev magento github:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/21643

https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/19095

Comment: 32000 is the constant value for "All Groups", defined in ```vendor/magento/module-customer/Api/Data/GroupInterface.php```. The error occurs because there is no configured minimum sale quantity where one is expected (but not supplied by default).